# Countably Compact, Separable, $T_1$, Connected Space that is not Compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, separable-spaces

In Wilder's Topology of Manifolds, the following is stated on p. 43:

"It is well known that not every countably compact, separable, connected space is compact."

Hmm . . . I'm not sure just how well-known this is.  He also assumes the spaces in question are $T_1$.  Since a google search only pulled up a considerably more advanced paper, I figured MSE might be a good place to have this example.  Does anyone know a relatively easy one?

Really appreciate it!  I will scour Seebach a bit later if nobody wants to grab this problem.

Comment: Steen and Seebach will have no example as its [online database](https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=Countably%20Compact%20%2B%20T_1%20%2B%20Separable%20%2B%20Connected%20%2B%20~Compact) has none either.

Comment: [This survey paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4773/f33b676280ef71f24c6ffb397aa02ef8b91a.pdf) is a nice overview about efforts to construct a Hausdorff countably compact, separable, first countable and non-compact spaces. There are no known ZFC examples, but many under some assumption beyond ZFC. No connected examples are mentioned there. But at least it shows you cannot conclude compactness from the other properties (minus connectedness).

Comment: [Novak space](https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces/S000109) from Steen and Seebach's book is separable, countably compact, Tychonoff and non-compact in ZFC. Only connectedness is absent...

Comment: Regarding the paper, notice that the spaces constructed with the additional assumptions are shown to be scattered, even.

Comment: connectedness is a weird property that way. Most (to me) natural examples will not be connected, and sometimes we can connectify them (if they have no isolated points).. The paper even discusses trying to construct manifolds with these properties..

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure what he means by manifold.  Maybe generalized (homology) manifold?

Comment: No, a connected and locally Euclidean space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example mentioned in [this survey paper by Nyikos](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4773/f33b676280ef71f24c6ffb397aa02ef8b91a.pdf) is $X = \omega_1$ with the topology generated by the cofinite sets and the initial segments $[0,\alpha)$, $\alpha < \omega_1$. This is not Hausdorff, but does obey the other properties of $T_1$, connectedness, countable compactness and non-compactness, as is easy to see. So this gives a ZFC example of the non-implication.

The survey paper gives a nice overview of how hard it is to construct Hausdorff first-countable such spaces. Examples are known (like Ostaszewski spaces) but need an additional set-theoretical assumption. Connected such spaces are not yet known (most such set theory based examples tend to be scattered or zero-dimensional, quite the opposite of connected).